# Angular access to data outside of a method that subscribes to an observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular-services

> I want to be able to get access to data outside of my method with .subscribe

This is my Service which "works" fine

```
getSessionTracker(): Observable<ISessionTracker[]> {
    return this.http.get(this._url)
        .map((res: Response) => {
            let data = res.json();
            return data;
        })
       .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

**Component is where my trouble is**

```
sessionTrackers: ISessionTracker[] = [];  //  object array 

this.trackerService.getSessionTracker()
    .subscribe((sessionTrackers: ISessionTracker[]) => {
        this.sessionTrackers = sessionTrackers;
        console.log('real data in subscribe', this.sessionTrackers[0].SessionId);
    },
    (err: any) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('getSessionTracker()'));
```

// outside of function this does NOT work

```
 console.log('real data', this.sessionTrackers);
```

**2 problems**

1. console.log INSIDE method with .subscribe works if I do a console.log,  however with `this.sessionTrackers[0].SessionId`   it is undefined , but `this.this.sessionTrackers`
2. this data not working outside of method

How can I persist the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is a timing one. Since the service call is asynchronous, the data does not arrive immediately when the subscribe is called. Rather, when the response is returned from the service, the callback function defined as the argument to the subscribe method is then called.

That's why the console.log within the Subscribe works.

Here is a picture roughly outlining the order of the execution.

[image]

However, your code will retain the value when it is indeed retrieved.

So outside of the subscribe function, you just need to check for the existence of the value. Something like this:

```
if (this.sessionTrackers) { console.log(...) }
```

Or if you are binding to the data, you need to use `*ngIf` or the safe navigation operator (?).

If you are using reactive forms, then you may want to separate setting up the form model (using FormBuilder) and setting the default values.

I have an example of reactive forms here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms (check out the APM folder).

**ngOnInit**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
        productName: ['', [Validators.required,
                           Validators.minLength(3),
                           Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        productCode: ['', Validators.required],
        starRating: ['', NumberValidators.range(1, 5)],
        tags: this.fb.array([]),
        description: ''
    });

    // Read the product Id from the route parameter
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(
        params => {
            let id = +params['id'];
            this.getProduct(id);
        }
    );
}
```

This code sets up the reactive form and watches for changes to the route parameters. When the route parameter is set, it calls getProduct(id).

**getProduct**

```
getProduct(id: number): void {
    this.productService.getProduct(id)
        .subscribe(
            (product: IProduct) => this.onProductRetrieved(product),
            (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
}
```

This goes to get the data, somewhat similar to what you are doing. Notice that in the subscribe callback I'm calling another method: `onProductRetrieved`.

**onProductRetrieved**

```
onProductRetrieved(product: IProduct): void {
    if (this.productForm) {
        this.productForm.reset();
    }
    this.product = product;

    // Update the data on the form
    this.productForm.patchValue({
        productName: this.product.productName,
        productCode: this.product.productCode,
        starRating: this.product.starRating,
        description: this.product.description
    });
    this.productForm.setControl('tags', this.fb.array(this.product.tags || []));
}
```

Here is where I am setting the default values for the reactive form since I now know I *have* the data. You can use `setValue` or `patchValue` for this.

Comment: Hi Deb.   So I have an interface in which there is a SessionId , but  while inside the method I can spit out console log of sessionTrackers,   but not  sessionTrackers[0].SessionId     that is undefined which I don't get

Comment: so with reactive form , I have a lot of typescript in which I want to set values from the subscribed data,  so I won't be using *nfIf in the html for this  -

Comment: I updated my answer to include how I populate my reactive forms. Hope this helps.